# Javascript How to push item in object

Tags: javascript, arrays

```
var data = {items: [
    {id: "1", name: "Snatch", type: "crime"}
]};
```

And I would like to add the mark's key.

So the result would be:

```
var data = {items: [
    {id: "1", name: "Snatch", type: "crime", mark:"10"}
]};
```

How can I do ?
I tried to do `data.items.push({"mark": "10"})` but it adds another object which is not what I want.

Thanks.

Comment: "it adds another object" That's what pushing means.  It sounds like you don't want to push anything; you want to set a property.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Access the correct index and simply set the property

```
data.items[0].mark = "10";
```

Answer (score 0):

You may not need push here because you want to create a new key to n existig object. Here you need dot `(.)` to create a new key

```js
var data = {
  items: [{
    id: "1",
    name: "Snatch",
    type: "crime"
  }]
};

data.items[0].mark = "10";
console.log(data)
```

Answer (score 0):

And, if you want add “mark” property to all the items:

```
data.items.forEach(function(item, index) {
    data.items[index].mark = 10;
}
```